# VBA Assistance needed. trying to select a range of cells, cut, move and paste

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003

I have a spread sheet that is updated weekly. What i need to do is cut come of the cells and paste to a new location. I have never used macros or VBA before but I am getting frustrated with the amount of time I spend doing this. I know that I can use a macro but don't know how to write it.

I am trying to move the name of the hotel and resort to the left of the passengers title

R81C00  CHALET LE VALENTIN  SAUZE D'OULX

MR  HAYHOE  8

MR  GLOVER  2

This repeats throughout the spread sheet. The number of lines between the names is dependent on information further right in the sheet.

546L
***_*__*_*__*_*___***1    RESORT INFORMATION*

__*_*__*_*__*_*_*5    SKI/S.BOARD CARRIAGE*

__*_*__*_*__*_*_8    AD L/P BRN BF 31/12/99

what I would like to do here is move these lines onto the same line as the flight number (this is the same line as passenger details) and then delete the lines with no data. this way all the details would be on the same line and then i would just need to fill down for the hotel names.

thanks in advance for any help please let me know if i haven't explained it clearly.

Comment: This can easily be done. How far have you gotten writing the macro?

Comment: I have to confess I am a total beginner when it comes to writing Macros and VBA in general. What prompted me to try to find out was spending about 8 hours per week editing the same spreadsheet, I just know there has to be an easier way than cutting and pasting!

Comment: So should the final layout per line be: Hotel & Resort Name | Passenger Details | 546L | 1 Resort Info | 5 Ski/s.Board Carriage | 8 AD L/P BRN BF 31/12/99 or should it be something different?

Comment: @barrowc ideallly i would like it to read Hotel Name, Resort Name, passenger details, 546L, Ski Carriage, Lift Pass, Equipment, Ski School. The fields or Ski Carriage, Lift pass, Equipment and Ski school to pull through the number which is the first digit in the cell, add them to the first digit in any other cells relating to the initial line of text, with the same property i.e. L/P and put the total on the same line as the other text under the correct heading.

Comment: I've posted a partial answer but more info is needed to work up a full answer. Specifically, which columns do the various pieces of data appear in when you look at the current version of the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to keep this general enough to be of use to other people, the basic process to follow would be:

```
find the next hotel/resort combination
  find each passenger for that hotel/resort
    add in the details for the other attributes
  move on to the next passenger
move on to the next hotel/resort
```

If we start with finding the hotel/resort combination and we assume that this is on Sheet1 in column A in a single cell and that nothing else is in column A then we would need this macro:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()

Dim lngCurrRow As Long
Dim lngMaxRow As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lngMaxRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For lngCurrRow = 1 To lngMaxRow
        If (.Cells(lngCurrRow, 1).Value <> "") Then
            MsgBox .Cells(lngCurrRow, 1).Value
        End If
    Next lngCurrRow
End With

End Sub
```

This should pop up a message box with the name of each hotel/resort in turn.

All the code does is work out how many used rows there are on the worksheet (and stores that in `lngMaxRow`) and then works through every used row (using `lngCurrRow` to keep track of which row we are on) checking the value of the cell in column A on that row (the `.Cells(lngCurrRow, 1).Value` part). If there is something in that cell (the (`<> ""` part) then it displays the value of that cell.

The more difficult case is when there is other data in column A (e.g. if the passenger names were also in column A). In that scenario, we need a way to easily recognise what is a hotel/resort combination and what is a passenger name but I don't have enough info about your current structure to determine how to do that